# Groovy calling CountDownLatch.await() lead to hang

Tags: groovy, timer, async-await

I'm new to groovy and have this simple code snippet:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

CountDownLatch called = new CountDownLatch(1)

Timer timer = new Timer()
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    void run() {
        called.countDown()
    }
}, 0)

assert called.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Upon running on command line, it just hang there, nothing happen. I expect that this program should quit at once. So where did I get wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it's not `await` that leads to hanging in your case. It's just the `Timer`'s thread is not a **daemon**. The JVM cannot terminate until all remaining running threads are daemons. As `Thread#setDaemon()` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon-boolean-) states it:

> ...The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads.

So in your case

1. You can just specify that the timer's thread is a daemon

```
CountDownLatch called = new CountDownLatch(1)

Timer timer = new Timer(true) //true means the underlying thread is a daemon
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    void run() {
        called.countDown()
    }
}, 0)

assert called.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
println("It's not await that leads to hanging")
```

2. Or if for some reason you don't want your timer's thread to be a daemon. E.g. you want the timer to handle all the scheduled tasks before the JVM terminates. In this case you can just cancel the timer at some appropriate moment

```
CountDownLatch called = new CountDownLatch(1)

Timer timer = new Timer() //now the underlying thread is NOT a daemon
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    void run() {
        called.countDown()
    }
}, 0)

assert called.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
println("It's not await that leads to hanging")
timer.cancel()//now we are done. All scheduled tasks will be cancelled. However, the running one will finish its job
```

P.S. If you want more flexible way of scheduling you can take a look at [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). As `Timer`s javadoc says:

> ...It is effectively a more versatile replacement for the Timer/TimerTask combination, as it allows multiple service threads, accepts various time units, and doesn't require subclassing TimerTask (just implement Runnable). Configuring ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with one thread makes it equivalent to Timer.